# setVisitility item in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem now! I have custom ListView, there I have two TextView element. I want setVisibility(TextView.gone) for one TextView in ListView element. I don't  know how to do it

Write an example of how I can hide TextView ienter code heren all the items for ListView

ListView:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listResultAvia"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="auto" >

            <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/item -->
        </ListView>
```

Custom item for ListVIew:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTimeResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTimeResult2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Show me how I can hide textViewTimeResult2 in the onCreate. 
If I write:

```
TextView test = (TextView) findById(R.id.textViewTimeResult2);
test.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
```

My program crashed in start.

**ADD:**

I use answer below, but now I get empty ListView. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please post some of your code from Adapter at least.

Comment: Your application cannot find your textViewTimeResult2 on onCreate() because it is not in your activity layout, (probably not in main.xml)

textViewTimeResult2 can only be found in your listItems rows in your adapters getView()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your adapter you can try this code to hide the second textview.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_list_layout, null);
    TextView textOne = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
    TextView textTwo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTwo);

    textTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;
}
```

**ADDED:**
you can add a boolean that toggles inside your `onClick()` then modify the `getView()`;

```
    boolean hideTextTwo = false;

    onClick(View v){
      hideTextTwo = true;
      yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

    }


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_list_layout, null);
    TextView textOne = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
    TextView textTwo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTwo);

if(hideTextTwo){
    textTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: mInflater - that there should be?

Comment: Ah you can replace that line with `convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null)`

Comment: mInflater is a LayoutInflater, it is used to instantiate an xml layout to its corresponding View object - more on about this at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: And how I can activate this action after click button?

Comment: just wrap the code that sets the `textTwo` to GONE with a condition, once you click your button, set the condition to `true`, then notify you adapter so it will 'refresh it's items

Answer (score 1):

//in your adapter

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder.first_line=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_row1);

            holder.second_line=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.second_row);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }


//TODO: hiding the first_line in the listview 
            holder.first_line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.second_line.setText("");
return (convertView);
        }
```